# Using CSS display:inline-block or float:left with mixed amounts of text

Tags: css-float, css

Looking for some expert advice here about how best to style the following HTML:

```
<body>
-Some content-
<div class="parent" style="height:50%;">
<div class="child" style="background-color:#FF9999;">An image</div>
<div class="child" style="background-color:#9999FF;">Some text</div>
</div>
</body>
```

To obtain a result that behaves like this:

[image]

The criteria that I am working with are the following:

- The container div, .parent, is a block element and fills the entire width of the browser window.
- I know the width of the first/left inner div, in pixels but not as a percentage, based on the regularity of the images that will go there.
- I don't know the width of the second/right inner div - as it contains a variable amount of text that should automatically fill the entire space to the right, regardless of browser window width
- The height of the first/left div, when shorter than the second/right div, should stretch to the same height (here's the reason: the first/left div will have a right-border to set it off from the second/right div, and this border should be the height of the .parent div; however, the first/left div is not always present in the mark-up, in which case the border should not appear).
- I cannot use JavaScript trickery.

Solutions I have tried based on my experience and help from web sources:

1. Float:
   The traditional method that uses float:left leaves me apparently unable to stretch the first/left div to the (variable) height of either its sibling or .parent.
2. Inline-block:
   .parent {background-color:#999999;}
   .parent > .child {display:inline-block;vertical-align:top;height:100%;}

Using display:inline-block appears to work like a charm when the text in the second/right div is not enough to fill an entire line.  The moment there is more text, however, the second/right div grows as wide as the outer container will let it, forcing it to wrap under the first/right div.

Any insights would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using table based markup is not the answer.  However, iff you don't need to support IE7 or lower, you can use `display:table` to solve this.  Check out this demonstration i threw together.  Edit the amount of content in the second child div to see the effect.

[jsfiddle demonstrating display:table](http://jsfiddle.net/37bPS/10/)

```
.parent {
  display:table;
}

.child {
  display:table-cell;
}
```

Basically, you tell the `parent` element to act like a table, the two `child` elements to act like table cells. This gives you the benefits of the table layout without the accessibility problems and extra markup of html tables.  As I mentioned though, this **doesn't work in IE7**.  If you need old IE support, you'll have to resort to less graceful workarounds :(

Comment: Thank you!  I am lucky I guess that I don't need IE support for this (I'm doing my testing in Chrome, but this is targeted mainly to iPhones and other mobile devices with modern browsers).

Using display:table and display:table-cell was a simple and elegant solution that fit my criteria/constraints (to which I should have added, no table markup!).  I had come across it in my search for a solution, documented right alongside display:inline-block, but had shied away from it because of the stigma I still associate with actual tables.  No more - thank you again for the help, I needed the nudge!

Comment: glad it worked for you.  since you mentioned targeting primarily mobile devices, you might also look into the [flexible box model](http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2011/09/19/css3-flexible-box-layout-explained/).  desktop browser support has been sketchy, but i've heard that mobile browsers are actually supposed to have decent support for it.  It gives you a *lot* of options for solving layout issues.

Comment: Flexible boxes, huh?  I must live under a rock.  Veeeery interesting...  thanks for sharing that link!

Answer (score 0):

While tables have gotten a bad reputation, this would be a good application for one.

```
<body>
    -Some content-
    <table class="parent" style="height:50%;">
        <tr>
            <td class="child" style="background-color:#FF9999;" width="10">An image</td>
            <td class="child" style="background-color:#9999FF;">Some text</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</body>
```

If you set the width to a minimum, it will push your content over even if it's larger, and no matter which column is taller, it will push the overall content box down.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion - I was really trying to stay away from table markup though.  In the end, I went with CSS-based tables (using the other solver's suggestion of display:table and display:table-cell - which I used to consider cheating, but really fundamentally you are right in the sense that some situations simply call for a table).  Now that I know how to keep table markup out of my code, I may warm back up to them after so many years of shunning!